# Simulating an HTTP Request through HTML

Tags: php, html, http, http-headers

(I know this is a silly question ;) )

It's possible simulate some HTTP response through HTML  http-equiv Attribute, like:

- Content-Security-Policy
- Content-Length
- Content-Encoding
- Default-Style
- Window-Target

> [HTML  http-equiv Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp)
>
> The http-equiv attribute provides an HTTP header for the
> information/value of the content attribute.
>
> The http-equiv attribute can be used to simulate an HTTP response
> header.

Now, there is a way to simulate some of **HTTP Requests** through HTML?

For example instead of sending HTTP Header `WWW-Authenticate` through PHP, embed it inside HTML?

`<?php header("WWW-Authenticate: Basic"); ?>`

Comment: with pure HTML no, its just a markup language

Comment: Well http-equiv attribute simulates http response headers. Only following values for http-equiv are supported: "content-type", "default-style" and "refresh"

Comment: @nadir-latif besides these values other values are acceptable too. Like: Content-Security-Policy,
Content-Length,
Content-Encoding,
Default-Style,
Window-Target &...

Comment: https://www.keycdn.com/support/http-equiv
---------------
http://www.standardista.com/html5/http-equiv-the-meta-attribute-explained/